# Когда запускается onCreate и onUpgrade у SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: android, sqlite

Когда запускается `onCreate` и `onUpgrade` у `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Я делаю отладку прямо на устройстве без рут прав. Поэтому я не вижу саму базу.

Как дропнуть именно базу данных, а не таблицу? Потому что при повторном запуске программы `onCreate` и `onUpgrade` не запускаются и я не могу изменить структуру таблиц. Потому что даже `drop table` из `onUpgrade` не могу запустить, так как сама `onUpgrade` не запускается. Постоянно приходится менять имя базы в запуске `super(context, "mydb12", null, 1);`

Comment: А как удалить базу из onConfigure?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Как следует из [первой же ссылки в гугле](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), `onCreate` запускается для создания новой БД, `onUpdate` - для обновления существующей. Обновление происходит, если версия БД ниже, чем текущая.

Вместо изменения имени БД, вам стоило бы увеличивать на 1 номер версии - это привело бы к вызову `onUpdate`.

Если БД при отладке меняется так часто, что проще пересоздавать ее заново - можно использовать метод `onConfigure`, который вызывается раньше, чем БД открывается - и там просто удалить файл базы данных.

Кстати, этот файл можно удалить в любом другом месте вашей программы - ведь это просто файл, и программа совершенно точно имеет к нему доступ.

Answer (score 1):

Эти два события стартуют когда читаешь бд. Я делаю так (запускаю при старте майн активити)

```
public static void init (){
    MySQLiteOpenHelper myHelper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(App.appContext);
    myHelper.getReadableDatabase(); //- сработает конструктор, "super(context, "mydb12", null, 1);" 
    myHelper.close();
}
```

При этом, чтобы сработало `onUpgrage`, надо чтобы версия бд сменилась, т.е. в твоем `super(context, "mydb12", null, 1);` - последний аргумент надо сменить (увеличить - для срабатывания `onUpgrade` или уменьшить (но не меньше 1 :), чтобы сработало `onDowngrade`)).

Одним махом удалить всю базу данных кодом не знаю как, удаляю все таблицы в цикле

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    ArrayList<MyTable> allTables = MySQLiteOpenHelper.getAllTableDescriptions();
    for(MyTable table: allTables){
        table.create(db);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    ArrayList<MyTable> allTables = MySQLiteOpenHelper.getAllTableDescriptions();
    for(MyTable table: allTables){
        table.drop(db,false);
    }
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: вот и помогай людям после этого:) минусят.. а за что?

Comment: Это не я минусовал

Answer (score 0):

> Когда запускается onCreate и onUpgrade у SQLiteOpenHelper?

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос - при повторном запуске программы onCreate и onUpgrade не запускаются.

В частности при обновлении приложения вы можете увеличить в конструкторе SQLiteOpenHelper версию, и при первом запуске будет вызван `onUpgrade`

Чтобы удалить базу данных - удалите полностью приложение с девайса.